# How to run a background PHP function with a POST variable using exec()?

Tags: php, background, execute

```
exec('php convert.php >> convert.log &');
```

This is the sample code I found, but here's what I want to do.

1. Run convert.php with 1 or more POST
   variables.
2. Execute the function in the
       background in case the user leaves
       our website.
3. Run multiple instances
       of convert.php in the background in
       case more than 1 user on the site at one time.

Comment: That seems like a really bad method of running a function in the background. There are better ways than calling exec() on another php script. What is your end goal?

Comment: My end goal is to run this second script in case the user leaves our website while it's still running.

Comment: Also, It's accessing a user's IMAP, so I'd like to be able to use a user's password while they're on our website so I don't have to store a password in our database.  It'd be optimal to store the password with 2 way encryption so I could use a cron job later in the evening to run this process, but I don't think it's the most secure solution.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to execute the process in another process just to ensure that it continues to run. PHP has a built in feature for that.

[ignore_user_abort()](http://php.net/ignore_user_abort) if true the current script will finish even if the user leaves while it's running.

Edit: as pointed out in comment you also need to disable time limit. Use [set_time_limit(0)](http://php.net/set_time_limit)

Comment: you need to disable max_execution_time too (set_time_limit(0)).